# Записать в один массив несколько элементов другого массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какая-то функция, которой можно было бы упростить следующий код:

```
$arr1[]; //1000 элементов

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $arr2[] = $arr1[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На глаза попалась нужная функция [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php):

```
$arr2 = array_slice($arr1, 0, 100);
```

Comment: Ну вот видите - сами вполне решили) - В общем - обращайтесь, ежели чего. И понадобилось Вам всего 9 минут на это)